# Prevent LightBox auto close

Tags: 7, javascript

Module: https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2

Once lightbox pop up, it will auto close within few second.

Am I am to stop it auto close till user click closed button?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: @Geoff Nope. Do you mean it wont auto close?

Comment: does it close after the last image in the slideshow? That is [a feature](https://www.drupal.org/node/144485). Or does it close randomly? Otherwise, could you give a bit more info on how you are using Lightbox2? Within a view? On a node? How many images? Which settings? etc...

Comment: @SidneyGijzen I add the lightbox 2 feature at content type. Under manage display I change image to lightbox. Anyway, I realize it only happen at my first image. The rest is fine. I wonder why.

Comment: That is indeed strange. Without any errors showing on page load (e.g. in Firebug), I don't have a clue what it could be. It might be worth trying to enable Lightbox2 on another content type and see if the issue persists. If so, then at least we can confirm whether it is something content type specific or not...